# Select the text of a reply given a parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table  `oc_review`:

```
review_id  product_id customer_id author text                                    rating  status date_added          date_modified       parent_id 
        3           0           3 12345  123456123123123123123123123123               5       0 2014-11-12 14:03:04 0000-00-00 00:00:00      NULL 
        4           0           3 Jacky  awefawefawefawefawefawefawefawefawefawef     5       0 2014-11-12 14:19:24 0000-00-00 00:00:00      NULL 
        5           0           3 Jacky  2134123412341234123412412341234124134        1       0 2014-11-12 14:20:34 0000-00-00 00:00:00      NULL
```

I am currently trying to select the `text` based on where the `review_id` is equal to the `parent_id`.

In the example showed above, the `parent_id` is `null` for the three rows, since each `review_id` does not contain a "reply". A "Reply" would look like this:

```
     1124        1635           0 Admin I am really sorry you had a bad exper...     1       0 2014-li-13 16:01:28 0000-00-00 00:00:00       123
```

What that means is, `review_id` `124` is a "reply" to the `parent_id` `123`. Or even more simpler, `review_id` `123` has a child that is `review_id` `124`.

My question is, how do I select the `text` of the reply (the child) given a `parent_id`? I tried:

```
SELECT text FROM oc_review ON (review_id = parent_id) WHERE review_id = 123;
```

The above code snippet only returned an empty set.

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted and how I could improve?

Comment: probably because you included hard-to-read screenshots of your data, rather than pasting it in as text.

Comment: I decided against it since the number of columns meant the original formatting would be mangled in text. It looked really ugly.

Comment: now that it's been edited, it looks fine to me. The scrollbars allow it to be laid out without compromising readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use join in this particular situation:

```
SELECT oc.text 
FROM oc_review o 
LEFT JOIN oc_review oc 
ON (o.review_id = oc.parent_id) 
WHERE o.review_id = 123;
```

Explanation:

- SELECT oc.text - We'll take `text` from joined table
- FROM oc_review o - We take the information from table `oc_review` with alias `o`
- LEFT JOIN oc_review oc - We doing left self join and setting alias of self join to `oc`
- ON (o.review_id = oc.parent_id) - We join if main table `review_id` equals to `parent_id` of joined table
- WHERE o.review_id = 123 - Where main table's `review_id` is 123

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT r.text
FROM oc_review r
WHERE parent_id = 123;
```